# Closed-form solutions for a combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, multinomial-coefficients

Consider a binary string of length $n$. We call the string *good* if the number of zeros and ones in the string are at most $m$.

**Example:** Let $n=4$ and $m=2$. Then the binary string `1010` is good, while the binary string `0010` is not.

**Example:** Let $n=4$ and $m=1$. Then no good string exists.

To count the number of good binary strings, one can use the following formula:

$$f(n,m) = \sum_{i=n-m}^{m} \binom{n}{i}$$

Mathematica derives the following closed-form for $f$:

$$\binom{n}{n-m} \cdot {}_{2}F_{1} \Big(1; -m; 1 - m + n; -1 \Big) 
- \binom{n}{m+1} \cdot {}_{2}F_{1} \Big(1; 1 + m - n; 2 + m; -1 \Big) \,,$$

where ${}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

---

Now consider the same problem, this time for **ternary** strings of length $n$: The string is *good* if the number of zeros, ones, and twos in the string are at most $m$.

**Example:** Let $n=4$ and $m=2$. Then the ternary string `0120` is good, while `0001` is not.

To count the number of good ternary strings, one can use the following formula (which uses the notation for [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials)):

$$g(n,m) = \sum_{i=n-2m}^{m} \sum_{j=n-m-i}^{m} \binom{n}{i,j,n-i-j}$$

> **Q1.** Is it possible to write the closed-form solution for $g(n,m)$ as we did for $f(n,m)$, perhaps using [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)?
>
> **Q2.** More generally, is it possible to derive closed-form solutions if the string is consist of $k$ symbols? ($k=2,3$ for binary and ternary strings, respectively)

Comment: Haven't you *found* a closed formula already?

Comment: "We call the string good if the number of zeros and ones in the string are at most $m$."  This definition implies every string will be "good" if $m \geq n/2$... right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Yes.

Comment: But won't *every* string be good under your definition, regardless of $m$, because *either* there will be more $1$s than $m$ or more $0$s than $m$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: No. Assume $n=4$ and $m=2$. The string `0000` is not good, even though the number of $0$s is more than $m$.

Comment: OK.  I (mis)read the original posting as saying that a string is good if the number of $0$s is greater than $m$ *and* we call it good if the number of $1$s is greater than $m$.  All clear now.